# Drawing an ellipse with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw only part of an ellipse using TikZ? I was only the top left quarter of it. I tried to use a white square box to hide the rest, but that is a tedious and ineffective method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Next time, please remember to provide a Minimum (non-)Working Example.

In this case, just draw it as an arc:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw  (0,0) arc (-180:-270:8 and 4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: quarter ellipse]

Answer (score 3):

Use `\clip`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (-8cm,0) rectangle (0,4cm);
    \draw  (0,0) ellipse(8cm and 4cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun solution with PSTricks.

### `\psellipticarc`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,dimen=monkey](8,6)
    \psellipse[linestyle=dashed](4,3)(3,2)
    \psellipticarc[linecolor=red,linewidth=3pt](4,3)(3,2){90}{180}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### `\psparametricplot`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,dimen=monkey](8,6)
    \psellipse[linestyle=dashed](4,3)(3,2)
    \psparametricplot[algebraic,linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt]{Pi 2 div}{Pi}{3*cos(t)+4|2*sin(t)+3}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]